# How can I set the space between lines in a plot?

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

I am using data of a matrix (a lot by 3) to make a 3D graph. I need to specify the jump line (or spaces between lines) in the graph. I didn't find what command I can set this?

Here is the code, it's very simple. I can't share the data file but it is huge, like as many nubmers of rows and just 3 columns. I want to configure the graph **as if it only showed in the graph 1 line every 5 lines**.

```
k= fopen('propagation.dat','r'); 
p= textscan(k,'%f %f %f'); 
fclose(k); % fecha o arquivo
xn=p{1,1};
yn=p{1,2};
zn=p{1,3};
plot3(xn,yn,zn,'linewidth',0.1)
xlabel('Name X')
ylabel('Name Y')
zlabel('Name Z')
title('Title')
```

[image: Graph here]

Comment: your data is located in specific x locations. Change those locations.

Comment: @AnderBiguri You mean I have to delete certain rows from the variable? I would like to set this in the graphical configuration (if exist) in Matlab.

Comment: No, I mean you did `plot3(x,y,z)`, change the values of `x` to e.g. `x1=x/2` and you will plot closer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri If you use 'x1 = x / 2' or 'x1 = x * 2' the scale (the axes) will change and the graph will be wrong.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked?

Comment: Maybe a combination of stretching the figure and looking at it from a different angle would be good enough...?

Comment: Please include the code you use for plotting, and describe your desired outcome. Fewer lines? Same number but further apart? Most of us don’t know what you know, so it’ll be easier to help you if make all your domain-specific assumptions clear. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the question to specifying better.  I want to config my graph to it make as it only show 1 line at each 5 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to replicate your plot, this is what I think your data looks like:

```
[xn,yn] = meshgrid(linspace(0,0.5,14),linspace(-15,15,100));
zn = exp(-2*yn.^2).*xn;
xn = xn(:);
yn = yn(:);
zn = zn(:);

figure
plot3(xn,yn,zn)
set(gca,'ylim',[-10,10],'zlim',[0,2]);
box off
```

[image]

What you have going on here is that there's a single line being drawn, so the point at the end of the first line is being connected to the point at the beginning of the second line. This creates a diagonal, straight line in between your data lines. To avoid those lines from showing, add NaN values to your data, at the end of each line. You can do that like this:

```
index = find(diff(yn)<0);
zn(index) = nan;

figure
plot3(xn,yn,zn)
set(gca,'ylim',[-10,10],'zlim',[0,2]);
box off
```

[image]

After that fix, if you want to further reduce the number of lines plotted, you need to remove whole lines, not individual points along each line like in the other answer. This is a bit more complicated, but can be accomplished like this:

```
len = index(1);
index = [0;index]+1;
index = index(1:3:end); % every 3rd line -- change to select how many lines to plot
elems = ((0:len) + index).'; % implicit singleton expansion
%elems = bsxfun(@plus,0:len,index).'; % use this instead if the previous line doesn't work
elems = elems(:);
xn = xn(elems);
yn = yn(elems);
zn = zn(elems);

figure
plot3(xn,yn,zn)
set(gca,'ylim',[-10,10],'zlim',[0,2]);
box off
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Would you also know how I can remove the lines that cross behind in your second chart?

Comment: @Gabriel: That is more difficult. You could plot vertical patches instead of lines, so that the space underneath the line becomes opaque. The alternative is to reshape your data to be a regular grid (see [`griddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html)), and use [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) to plot it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `plot3` line to following:

```
plot3(xn(1:5:end), yn(1:5:end), zn(1:5:end), 'linewidth', 0.1)
```